# Interfaces and Object Oriented Design

Tags: oop, interface

I have a main form called Form1.  On that form I have a usercontrol called XYZUserControl which has a tabcontrol. On tab1 is a usercontrol called Control1. On tab2 is a usercontrol called Control2.

I need to reference Control2 from Control1 but don't know how to set up my code to do so. Im looking for something like: " reference to some interface or instance to XYZUserControl ".Control2.

Any ideas?

Comment: It will help if you can post some relevant code that you have tried. At-least the class structures and their relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think interfaces are going to help you here. More likely you would just use the control hierarchy.

From `Control1`, walk up the control tree via the `Parent` property until you get to `XYZUserControl`, then walk back down again by iterating over the child `Controls` property.

It's not pretty or elegant, but without any further insight into your code or exactly what you are trying to achieve via this linkage, it's hard to recommend anything else at this point.